# cant get the absolute coordinates of a button in android

Tags: android, button, coordinates

I am trying to retrieve the absolute coordinates of a button. I have done the following coding but its always returning 0. can anyone help me out.

```
       Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    int[] location = new int[2];
    b.getLocationOnScreen(location);

    for(int i=0;i<location.length;i++)
    {
        Log.i("hhhhhhhh",""+location[i]);
    }
    Log.i("wid hei",""+width+","+height);
```

Comment: what exactly is that code meant to do? You've created a point, and called it 'size' (although it can only be a single value), what exactly is returning 0?

Comment: the location array displays 0,

Comment: try to get it in any method or so..on a click event or so..

Comment: what does the line `Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);` actually assign to b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get location after view is drawn. Try following code in onCreate().

```
ViewTreeObserver vto=b.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int[] location = new int[2];
            b.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        }
});
```